# How do I validate multiple screens for payment gateway

Tags: c#, web-applications, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am creating a payment gateway in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC and need to prevent users from accessing the same screen on different tabs or browsers without using session or tempdata. How can I validate the screen?

It is reasonable to expect that the system should not allow a user to open the same screen with the same login on a different tab or another browser. If a user logs in with another browser or tab, the existing browser login should be logged out automatically to ensure the security of the user's account and prevent unauthorized access.

Comment: our web applications couldn't control browser actions, but requests from a new browser or a new tab of the same browser should be different, I mean, any time we open a tab to visit the same website, it should be a new request, we could define request id for each request, then force the authentication for eache request, if the user passed the authentications in 2 requests, then keep the latest still alive but kill the old request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.